# minimal $KC$ and (strongly) $KC$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

If $P$ is a topological property, then a space $(X, \tau)$ is said to be minimal $P$ (respectively, maximal) if $(X, \tau)$ has property $P$ but no topology on $X$ which is strictly smaller (respectively, strictly larger ) than $\tau$ has $P$.

A topological space is called $KC$ space if every compact subset is closed.

A topological space is called strongly $KC$ space if every countably compact subset is closed.

I know (strongly) $KC$ – space is topological property.

I want to know:

Is there a example of a minimal $KC$ but not minimal strongly $KC$ – space?

It is a fact that an infinite minimal strongly $KC$ space has a trivial convergent sequence, but it does not hold for minimal $KC$ space. I want an easy example to show it.

Comment: Another account posted exactly same question on MathOverflow. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/137870/minimal-strongly-kc .

Answer (score 2):

Since each compact space is countably compact, each minimal KC-space which is a strongly KC-space is a 
minimal strongly KC-space too. So we need an example of a minimal KC-space $X$ which is not a strongly KC-space. We can take as such the example an arbitrary Hausdorff compact space $X$ which has a non-closed countable compact subspace $Y$ (the latter conditions implies that $X$ is not a strongly KC-space).  The space $X$ is a KC-space, because each compact subset of a Hausdorff space is closed in it. Suppose that $X$ is a not minimal KC-space. Then there exists a topology $\tau’$, strictly weaker than the initial topology $\tau$ on $X$ such that is $(X,\tau’)$ is a KC-space. Hence there exists a set  $U\in\tau\setminus\tau’$.  Then the set $K=X\setminus U$ is compact subset of the space $(X,\tau)$ and therefore it is a compact subset of the space $X$ endowed with the weaker topology $\tau’$ too. But $K$ is not closed in $(X,\tau’)$, a contradiction. At last, as $X$ we can take a Tychonoff product $[0,1]^{\omega_1}$ and as $Y$ the $\sigma$-product $\{x\in [0,1]^{\omega_1}: |\{\alpha<\omega_1: x(\alpha)\not=0\}|\le\omega\}$. The space $X$ is compact by Tychonoff Theorem and it is well-known and easy to prove that $Y$ is a countably compact and not closed subspace of $X$.

Added: It seems the following. For each point $x\in X$ put $supp(x)=\{\alpha<\omega_1:x(\alpha)\not=0\}$ and for each subset $A$ of $X$ put $supp(A)=\bigcup\{supp(x):x\in A\}$. If $A$ is countable infinite subset of $Y$, 
then  the set $supp(A)$ is countable, because $supp(x)$ is countable for each point $x\in A\subset Y$. Therefore $A\subset Z=\prod\{X_\alpha: \alpha<\omega_1\}$ where $X_\alpha=[0;1]$ if $\alpha\in supp(A)$ and $X_\alpha=\{0\}$ in the opposite case. 
The Tychonoff theorem imply that $Z$ is compact. Since the set $supp(A)$ is countable, $Z\subset Y$. Therefore the set $A$ belongs to the compact set $Z$ and hence the set $A$ has a cluster point in $Z$.