# minimal KC - space and strongly minimal KC - space

Tags: general-topology

If P is a topological property, then a space $(X, \tau)$ is said to be minimal $P$ (respectively, maximal) if $(X, \tau)$ has property $P$ but no topology on $X$ which is strictly smaller (respectively, strictly larger ) than τ has P.

A topological space is called KC space if every compact subset is closed.

A topological space is called strongly KC space if every countably compact subset is closed.

can you help me and give an  easy example to show that a topological space is minimal KC - space but is not strongly minimal KC - space?

I found a example like: $X = \beta \omega$ ( the Stone-Čech compactification of natural numbers in " On Minimal Strongly KC - spaces " by Weihua Sun, Weihai, Yuming.example: 2.4 ) to show  that a topological space is minimal KC - space but is not strongly minimal KC - space, but it was ambiguous to me.

please give me a hand!

Comment: The same question at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/137870/minimal-strongly-kc and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453590/minimal-kc-and-strongly-kc. Isn't it some kind of spam? A second ago asking account was called Alireza instead of fatemeh (user 88002). User named fatemeh and then Alireza (MathOverflow user 37684) asked the same questions on MathOverflow. Also same quuestion here asked by maryam (MathExchange user 87927), maybe it's the same person.

Comment: @user87690 This user has been banned because of "poor contributions", yes.

Answer (score 2):

I'll continue my answer to [one of the previous questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/453967/71850). Since $\beta\omega$ is compact, it is a minimal KC-space. It rests to find a countable compact and not closed subset $Y$ of the space $X$. It should be easy. Theorem 3.6.14 from [Eng] implies that each infinite closed subset of $\beta N$ has cadinality $2^\frak c$ (as I understood, here $N$ should be a coountable infinite discrete space, that is homeomorphic to $\omega$). So for any non-isolated point $p\in\beta\omega$, the space $\beta\omega\setminus\{p\}$ should be countable compact, because each countable infinite subset $Z$ of $\beta\omega\setminus\{p\}$ should to have $2^\frak c$ cluster points different from $p$. Therefore $Z$ has a cluster point in $\beta\omega\setminus\{p\}$.

*References*

[Eng] Ryszard Engelking, General topology, Moscow, 1986, (in Russian) .

Comment: I read your answer to question that" is there minimal KC space but be strongly minimal KC. " you take X a Tychonoff product $ [0,1]^ω_{1} $ and as Y the $σ$ -product $ \{ x∈[0,1]^ ω_{1} :|\{α<ω_{1} :x(α)≠0 \}|≤ω \} $. The space X is compact and Y is countable compact? why Y is countable compact? can you explain it? Thanks.

Comment: @fatemeh I added some details to my answer to that question.

Comment: In this question, we must prove that every  infinite subset of X has a cluster point, but this cluster point do not belonge to that subset in order to be non closed, is it right? Thank you.

Comment: In the present question we should find a non-closed  countably compact subset $Y$ of $Z$. To assure the non-closedness of $Y$ we take as $Y$ a closed subset of $X$ without a non-isolated point $p$. To assure that $Y$ is countably compact, we remark that each countable infinite subset $Z$ of $Y$ has a lot of cluster points in $X$, therefore there exists a cluster point $q\in X$, which is different from $p$. Thus $q\in X\setminus \{p\}=Y$.